# Using Django templates in an iframe, 404 error

Tags: python, django, iframe, modal-dialog

I have a Django site set up with the home page being home.html. Within home.html is a modal that is set to open automatically a few seconds after the home page loads. Within the modal is an iframe that should display template1.html. However when the modal comes up I have a 404 and I'm told the page didn't match the url patterns I defined. I'm not entirely sure where or how I go about getting template1.html to display in the iframe. The user isn't clicking on the main page to bring up a new template, which is how I'm familiar with using Django. Do I need to create another url pattern or view to achieve this or am I way off? Here are my files:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url  
from disease import views  

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='disease_home'),  
    url(r'^disease/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'disease.views.disease', name='disease_disease'),  
    url(r'^treatment/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.treatment, name='disease_treatment'),
```

home.html modal:

```
<div id="challengeModal" class="reveal-modal xlarge">  
    < iframe seamless scrolling="no" src="challenge1.html" name="challenge1"  
id="challenge1"></iframe>  
< /div>
```

views.py:

```
 def home(request):  
    return render(request, "disease/home.html")`
```

Other views return the second template, template2.html, based on actions in template1.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is Yes, you'll need both another url pattern AND a view for your iframe.  An iframe is pretty much treated like an embedded browser window, it will make its own request to the server.

Answer (score 1):

iframe `src` is just a url to a resource.

For example you could load your `treatment` page into it using

`<iframe src="/treatment/1/"></iframe>`

You will need to create a view to serve your `challenge1.html` template and an url to route to that view